# using props component by other component in class App

Tags: reactjs

i want Button component to use the Questions component props in class App

```
class Questions extends React.Component  {
render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>what is the {this.props.Number1} X {this.props.Number2}</h1>
        </div>
    )
}
```

}

```
const Button = (props) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={props.click}>{props.choice}</button>
        </div>
        )
```

in the class app it throw error :Warning: Received NaN for the `children` attribute. If this is expected, cast the value to a string.

```
class App extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super()
    this.state = {
        count: 0,
        cicked: false
    }
    this.handelClick = this.handelClick.bind(this)
}
handelClick() {

    this.setState({
        count: this.state.count + 1,
        clicked: !this.state.clicked,
    })
    console.log(this.state.count)
}

render() {
    function getRandom(max) {
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(max));
    }


return (
    <div className="body">
        <Questions Number1={getRandom(10)} Number2={getRandom(10)} />
        <Button click={this.handelClick} choice={(this.props.Number1 * this.props.Number2)} />

  </div>
);
```

}
}

Comment: Number1 and Number2 props are not available to Button, you could use Number1 and Number2 in state and then you will be able to use those values for both components Questions and Button.

Comment: As answered here, you might nont have this.props.Number1 and this.props.Number2 in App, assign those numbers to a variable and pass the same var to both Button and Questions. - Plus, I wouldn't recomment defining functions inside render. The only thing render should do is to render the view :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that in App you don't have `props.Number1` nor `props.Number2`.
You have to generate them prior to render:

```
render() {
    function getRandom(max) {
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(max));
    }

    const N1 = getRandom(10)
    const N2 = getRandom(10)


    return (
      <div className="body">
          <Questions Number1={N1} Number2={N2} />
          <Button click={this.handelClick} choice={N1 * N2} />
      </div>
    );
}
```

I would also suggest to avoid defining `getRandom` in render, because it will be redefined each time your component will be rendered. Make it at class level.

#### Edit to change numbers on button click

```
class App extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super()
    this.state = {
        count: 0,
        cicked: false,
        number1: this.getRandom(10),
        number2: this.getRandom(10)
    }

    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this)
  }

  getRandom = max =>
    Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(max))

  handleClick() {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
        count: prevState.count + 1,
        clicked: !prevState.clicked,
        number1: this.getRandom(10),
        number2: this.getRandom(10)
    }))
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="body">
        <Questions
          Number1={ this.state.number1 }
          Number2={ this.state.number1 }
        />
        <Button
          click={ this.handleClick }
          choice={ this.state.number1 * this.state.number2 }
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: i need getRandom change every time i click the button i try  to put it in handelClick methode but it will generate only if i click the button and that's not what i need

Comment: Thank you need to generate the two numbers and save them in the state. I'm editing my answer.

Comment: thank you for your solution but i coudn't figure out where i will define getRandom function

Comment: I added the definition of the `getRandom` method at class level. Check it out.